# How to get latest value of child table (with a condition) using parent table primary key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one for hotel booking and another for booking status with values (Booked, Cancelled, Noshow). I need get the cancelled booking rows how to frame query in mysql

(note : initial status is booked if that booking is cancelled one new row added with the status as cancelled )

Table 1 - bookings

id  |   bookingNumber   |   check in    |   check out   |   rooms

1   |   BK01    |           2018-06-23   |  2018-06-24  |   1
2   |   BK02    |           2018-06-23   |  2018-06-24  |   3

Table 2 - Status

id   |    bookingNumber      |     Status

1    |    BK01         |       Booked

2    |    BK01         |       Cancelled

3    |    BK02         |       Booked

Expected answer: 
(Need only cancelled booking)
id  |  bookingNumber  |  checkin  |  checkout  |  rooms  |  status
1   |  BK01           | 2018-06-23| 2018-06-24 |   1     |  Cancelled

Comment: Table structure, data, expected result. A lot of things missing in this question.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use join with additional clause to join only rows with status cancelled

```
select b.*, s.status
from bookings b
left join booking_status s on b.bookingNumber = s.bookingNumber
                           and s.status = 'cancelled' Where s.status = 'canceled'
```

Comment: No, this query didn't work. I am getting 2 row for both booked and cancelled conditions.

Comment: @JohnBabu it will return all bookings and from  `booking_status` it will return only rows  where status = 'cancelled', If thats not what you want you can add expected output in your question

Answer (score 0):

Actually in second table you saving the event of hotel booking (which represented by status) as I understand . So you can use the join with where clause like that

```
select * from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.Id=t2.t1_id where t2.status 
='cancelled'
```

I think your table2 have the primary Id of table1 as foreign key.

As you updated the question , now you can use like this.

```
    select * from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.bookingNumber =t2.bookingNumber
    where t2.status  ='cancelled'
```

Comment: So, the second  query  will work. You should learn about join

Comment: BK01 row appeared for both the conditions

Comment: This also give 2 rows for booked condition but it should be display only one row.

Comment: can you post your query in comment

Comment: SELECT * FROM `bookings` t1 join status t2 on t1.bookingNumber= t2.bookingNumber where t2.status = 'booked'

Comment: @JohnBabu, you have been given two correct answers but you disapprove of them because you use an incorrect query? Why ask for status `booked` when you want `cancelled`?